# Update Stripe Price (payment_intent)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm currently creating a website where people can choose their subscription length (1/3/6/12 months) from a dropdown. Selecting one will open a modal which displays the Stripe payment forms.

Unfortunately, it only works if I split up the code into multiple files (see Stripe Docs example => https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart).

I don't know how I can update the price properly so it matches the selected subscription. PHP and HTML are not best friends, if no form is being submitted. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

I tried using form submits with iframe so I see the forms without page refresh, unfortunately the variables are not being transmitted to the "create.php" file since I have to use if statements to differ between the subscriptions.

Comment: I'd highly suggest looking at Stripe's low-code Pricing Table :https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table which does more or less what you want and is likely a better fit and faster way to launch for your level of web dev

Comment: Definitely will look into this. Seems to be very easy and handy, and might be the better solution here. Thanks for linking this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found a solution for this problem. I can't have the PaymentIntent Creation and the forms in the same file, so I definitely had to split up these two.

But I was able to use the Update Method for the PaymentIntent and use the forms in the same file. So now when someone selects a subscription from the dropdown, a form submit happens, which opens a bootstrap-modal in which I've embedded an iframe with the content of the file which handles the Update Method and displays the Stripe forms.

Maybe this helps someone, I think this is a pretty cool solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).